# What is `-p` used for `cron`?

Tags: cron

In [cron's manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html) (cronie)

```
-p     Allows Cron to accept any user set crontables.
```

I learned that `cron` daemon will implicitly search for and run the cron jobs defined in `/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.d/*` and `/var/spool/cron/cronstabs/*`.

What is `-p` used for?

Is it to explicitly tell `cron` to search for and run the cron jobs defined in a crontab file which is stored in some place other than those mentioned above?

Or is it to **copy** a crontab file stored in some place other than those mentioned above to one of the places mentioned above?

Does the cron on Debian or its derivatives  have `-p` option? I don't find `-p` on the manpage of `cron` on Ubuntu.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are really sure that there is an option `-p`, you are not using `cron` but something else - maybe a clone implementation. See the `cron` manpage: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1m/cron.1m.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `CAVEATS` section of the cronie's `cron(8)` man page says (emphasis mine):

> All crontab files have to be regular files or symlinks to regular
>   files, they must not be executable or writable for anyone else but
>   the owner.  **This requirement can be overridden by using the -p option**
>   on the crond command line.

So it *is* in fact documented on the man page, although not in the most obvious location.

Comment: Thanks.  Can the file argument to -p be anywhere in any filesystem, or must it be in either`/etc/cron.d/ or /varspool/cron/crontabs/?

Comment: The `-p` option takes no "file argument" and has no effect as to where the `cron` daemon looks for crontab files; it just switches the ownership/permission/filetype checks off. The `cron` daemon will still look for crontabs in three places: the file `/etc/crontab`, any files in directory `/etc/cron.d/`, and any files in directory `/var/spool/cron/`. These locations can apparently only be changed by modifying the `cron` source code.

Answer (score 4):

Good question.  It doesn't appear to be documented within the man page. Looking at the source, we see `-p` sets PermitAnyCrontab, see https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie/blob/master/src/cron.c#L703

```
        case 'p':
            PermitAnyCrontab = 1;
```

Which in turn gets used https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie/blob/40b7164227a17058afb4f3d837ebb3263943e2e6/src/database.c#L89

Makes `cron` less fussy about the crontab file's state (can be a non-regular file, can have a different owner, can have a mode that's not 400, can have a link count other than 1).

```
if (PermitAnyCrontab == 0) {
    if (!S_ISREG(statbuf.st_mode)) {
        log_it(uname, pid, "NOT REGULAR", tabname, 0);
        close(crontab_fd);
        return (-1);
    }
    if ((statbuf.st_mode & 07533) != 0400) {
        log_it(uname, pid, "BAD FILE MODE", tabname, 0);
        close(crontab_fd);
        return (-1);
    }
    if (statbuf.st_uid != ROOT_UID && (pw == NULL ||
            statbuf.st_uid != pw->pw_uid ||
            strcmp(uname, pw->pw_name) != 0)) {
        log_it(uname, pid, "WRONG FILE OWNER", tabname, 0);
        close(crontab_fd);
        return (-1);
    }
    if (pw && statbuf.st_nlink != 1) {
        log_it(uname, pid, "BAD LINK COUNT", tabname, 0);
        close(crontab_fd);
        return (-1);
    }
}
```

While it's clearly present within cronie, such a feature is not present in Vixie Cron (https://github.com/svagner/vixie-cron)

Comment: Thanks. Can such a crontab file specified by -p be stored anywhere? Must it be user-specific crontab file, not system crontab file?

Comment: It can be a symlink to elsewhere.  All it does is bypass a safeguards / checks really.  Note it's crond itself, not crontab.

Comment: Do you mean the file argument to -p must still be in either`/etc/cron.d/ or /varspool/cron/crontabs/, not anywhere in any filesystem?

Comment: @Tim The argument `-p` must be given the cron daemon `crond`. On most systems, you need to modify the init script resp. the systemd configuration file to accomplish this.